# performSelector: afterDelay: not being called until mouse up

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a NSSlider object (continuous mode on) which is connected to the outlet method

```
- (IBAction)UpdateValueFromSlider:(id)sender {
    [self performSelector:@selector(OutputData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.02];
}
```

which is called as desired whenever the slider is moved (and not just when the mouse goes up).

However, the method `OutputData` itself is only called when the mouse goes up, and not if I take the slider and drag it around, keeping the mouse down.

Why is this occurring, and how do I call `OutputData` with a slight delay whenever the slider is updated?

Comment: Why do you want a delay?

Comment: what about using the equivalent GCD function? Or call a regular method from the snippet you're showing and use `dispatch_after.... ` in the method that's being called to delay whatever logic you need to have delayed..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slider's tracking loop is presumably running the run loop in a different run loop mode – probably `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode`.  The `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method fires only when the run loop runs in `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`; as the doc for that method says, if you want the message to be dequeued in other run loop modes, you should use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:inModes:` instead.  For the `inModes:` parameter you could pass an `NSArray` with `NSDefaultRunLoopMode` and `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode` in it; or even better, probably, you could simply pass `NSRunLoopCommonModes`, which should cover your bases regardless of what Apple might do with the run loop mode in the future.